# awk compare columns from two files and print the file 2 column if it is not seen in file1

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Eg. file 1

```
"ACCOUNT_ID","CTN","NAME","GATEWAY_GUID","DEVICE_GUID","CATALOG_ID","FW_VERSION","DATE_CREATED","STATUS_ID","LOCATION_CODE","BAN","Market_Area","State","IMEI","HW_MODEL"
"306875",="9404653975","14-052917 14-052917","313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03","0",="000010000010004","FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5","06/24/2014 14:32:38","0",="0003013034",="177046772949","DLS","TX",="351612051721824","Cisco DLC-100"
"306875",="9404653975","14-052917 14-052917","7EED6EE61F0949EE99554D4D4F09E4FE","ACFF000001",="000010901000004","1.2.14","06/24/2014 21:28:17","0",="",="177046772949","DLS","TX",="351612051721824",""
"306875",="9404653975","14-052917 14-052917","D57DAE988A1C482EA3217312EDC7466E ","ACFF010904",="000010907000004","","12/16/2015 23:39:21","0",="",="177046772949","DLS","TX",="351612051721824",""
```

file 2

```
account,ban,ctn,first_name,last_name,device_gateway_guid,device_id,device_cat_id,IMEI,device_fw_vrsn,date_created,device_status,subscription_created,subscription_name,subscription_market,date
DL!813269 , 418069632891 , undefined , MUHAMMAD , ANJUM , 313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03, ACFF010904 , 00010907000004 , 351612054025777 ,  , 2015-12-18 19:45:31 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , WAS , undefined
DL!782477 , 523266997720 , undefined , SAM , MAURER , 7EED6EE61F0949EE99554D4D4F09E4FE , 0 , 00010000010004 , 351612053801194 , FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5 , 2015-12-18 19:02:27 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , FLP , 2015-07-29 09:07:22
DL!926875 , 578172109430 , undefined , TRACY , BUSH , D57DAE988A1C482EA3217312EDC7466E , 0 , 00010000010004 , 351612054481798 , FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5 , 2016-01-23 16:09:21 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , GLF , 2015-11-06 02:26:31
"306875",="9404653975","14-052917 14-052917","313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03","0",="313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03","FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5","06/24/2014 14:32:38","0",="0003013034",="177046772949","DLS","TX",="351612051721824","Cisco DLC-100"
```

I want to compare the file1's "GATEWAY_GUID" column with file2's device_gateway_guid column. Output should be all the records of file2 that are not seen in file1.

Eg: if file 1 has 10 records and file 2 has 5000 records out of 5 of them are same as file 1. Then my output file should show that missing 5 column values of file 1 that are not seen in file2.

So far, I tried the below script but of no use. Any help appreciated.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$6]++;next};c[$4] == 0' s2_1.csv s1_1.csv > compares1s2.csv
```

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You have twenty columns or so (a guess — I haven't counted) in each file that could be omitted from your example. That would make it much easier for us to see what's going on, and would make it much easier for you to see what's going on.  You'll need to graduate to the full size files eventually, but you can get it to work on a simpler system.

Comment: One problem in the command line shown is that you've not set the field separator to comma (`-F ,` would fix that).  Is that screwing everything up?  Did you try printing any of the data you were reading — such as the value in `$6` in the `NR==FNR` segment?  I also distrust the `;` between segments — it may be OK, but I'd certainly not put it there myself.

Comment: You also have a number of fields that start with an `=` sign, such as `…,="000010000010004",…`.  That means that a full CSV parser will treat the field as containing that `=` sign and the two double quotes (and the digits in between).  It's odd formatting, but it appears multiple times; it isn't just a one-off accident.

Answer (score 0):

First step: parse file1 so you only have the relevant information:

```
grep -v "GATEWAY_GUID" file1 | cut -d'"' -f8 
# or more difficult to read
sed -n '2,$ s/\([^,]*,\)\{3\}"\([^"]*\).*/\2/p' file1
```

Depending on your possible formats of your input you might need to change this.
Output first step

```
313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03
7EED6EE61F0949EE99554D4D4F09E4FE
D57DAE988A1C482EA3217312EDC7466E
```

Now you would like to do something like

```
grep -Ev "313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03|7EED6EE61F0949EE99554D4D4F09E4FE|D57DAE988A1C482EA3217312EDC7466E" file2
```

`grep` has an option to read the search strings from a file, so this could be changed into

```
grep -EvFxf tempfile_with_search_keys file2
```

You can keep the temp file "in memory" using "process substitution":

```
grep -EvFxf <(some_command) file2
```

For the some_command I can use the first command parsing file1

```
grep -EvFxf <(grep -v "GATEWAY_GUID" file1 | cut -d'"' -f8) file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN   { FS="[,\"]";}
    FNR==NR {  
      a[ $11 ] ++;
      next;
    }

    { tmp = gensub(/[ ]+/, "", "g", $6); 
      if( !( tmp in a)  ) print tmp; 
    }
' ff1.csv ff2.csv
```

- assuming the filesnames are ff1.csv and ff2.csv
- the provided example in the question has spaces in the second file and some rows have quotes some have no quotes
- the quotes are dealt with in the assignment to `FS`
- the spaces in the values in the second file are removed with the `gensub`
- tested with GNU awk 4 on linux

Comment: You should mention it's non-POSIX due to gensub() and so will only work on some awk variants (e.g. gawk).

Answer (score 0):

Kinda one-off, but it works on your example data:

```
 awk -F, 'NR==FNR {
              s=$4; 
              gsub("\"", "", s); 
              gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"", s); 
              arr[s]++} 
          NR>FNR && FNR>1 {
              s=$6; 
              gsub("\"", "", s); 
              gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"", s); 
              sub(/=/,"",s); 
              if (!(s in arr))
                  print s;
              }' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your expected output so idk if this is what you want or not but here you go anyway:

```
$ awk -F'[ "]*,[ "]*' 'NR==FNR{a[$4];next} (FNR==1) || ($6 in a)' file1 file2
account,ban,ctn,first_name,last_name,device_gateway_guid,device_id,device_cat_id,IMEI,device_fw_vrsn,date_created,device_status,subscription_created,subscription_name,subscription_market,date
DL!813269 , 418069632891 , undefined , MUHAMMAD , ANJUM , 313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03, ACFF010904 , 00010907000004 , 351612054025777 ,  , 2015-12-18 19:45:31 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , WAS , undefined
DL!782477 , 523266997720 , undefined , SAM , MAURER , 7EED6EE61F0949EE99554D4D4F09E4FE , 0 , 00010000010004 , 351612053801194 , FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5 , 2015-12-18 19:02:27 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , FLP , 2015-07-29 09:07:22
DL!926875 , 578172109430 , undefined , TRACY , BUSH , D57DAE988A1C482EA3217312EDC7466E , 0 , 00010000010004 , 351612054481798 , FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5 , 2016-01-23 16:09:21 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , GLF , 2015-11-06 02:26:31
```